# Calling zmodload from a script

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to understand how zsh modules are loaded. According to the docs:

> Some optional parts of zsh are in modules, separate from the core of the shell. Each of these modules may be linked in to the shell at build time, or can be dynamically linked while the shell is running if the installation supports this feature. Modules are linked at runtime with
>   the zmodload command.

If I startup a new shell and run the command `zmodload` it displays the currently loaded modules (zsh/datetime *is not* loaded).

I can load it at run time using `zmodload zsh/datetime`. If I then run `zmodload` again, I can see that it's now listed.

However, when I execute the script like this, the zmodload command can't be found:

```
%./testload.zsh

#!/usr/bin/env zsh
zmodload zsh/datetime
echo "EPOCHSECONDS: $EPOCHSECONDS"

./testload.zsh: line 3: zmodload: command not found
```

But, if I execute the script while invoking a new zsh shell, it runs successfully:

```
% zsh testload.zsh

#!/usr/bin/env zsh
zmodload zsh/datetime
echo "EPOCHSECONDS: $EPOCHSECONDS"

EPOCHSECONDS: 1501004101
```

Any idea why this behavior is occurring?

Comment: Interesting. I can't seem to replicate this behaviour: https://asciinema.org/a/iDHpxapWWSkPoHh1OcvuPbMBG - makes me wonder what's different about your system. What OS are you using? Did you install ZSH through your system's package manager or from source?

Comment: Just rechecked, my shebang was typo'd. When it's fixed, it works as expected. What's strange though, is even with the shebang typo'd it's still executing as a zsh script and zsh commands work (except for zmodload): https://asciinema.org/a/Kb0TvRfxCw9yTG9wcVnNcjyhB

Comment: @nfarrar Not that strange. As the typo was that the line started with `##!` instead of `#!` the system did not recognize it as a shebang line. Without a shebang most systems fall back onto the default shell, most likely `/bin/sh`. This is probably not a copy of/link to `zsh`, so it would not know the *zsh builtin* `zmodload`.

Comment: That was my first thought as well. So I put 'echo $SHELL' in the script as well, and in both cases it's /usr/local/bin/zsh.

Comment: `$SHELL` refers to the user's interactive/login shell, not the shell executing the script. https://asciinema.org/a/8DlK6OcP3XXYKZd0vf88xnLvN?t=5

Comment: @nfarrar Since you've resolved your issue, can you close the question, please?